# Why do we need to send reference of cin to a function instead of just using Cin in that function?

Tags: c++

Why do we need to send reference of cin to a function instead of just using Cin in that function?

This function is to fill the vector. Why is the first argument istream& in required? Can't we simply us cin. And also why a reference of type istream is returned? This image is from the book accelerated c++

[image]

Comment: Please edit your post to add your code *as text* not as an image

Comment: If you write a function to add two numbers, why do you pass 2 parameters? Maybe next time you call the function you dont want to pass `cin` but read from a file, or from some other inputstream....

Comment: Yes I know that. But what is the need of passing it at all. We can simply pass only the vector and use cin to fill the vector isnt it?

Comment: @user8114776 - there are many other types of istream derived classes which may be used, that's the reason

Comment: `std::ifstream input_file("sample.txt"); read_fw(input_file, my_vec);` would read from a file rather than `std::cin`

Answer (score 2):

> Why do we need to send reference of cin to a function instead of just using Cin in that function? Why is the first argument istream& in required? Can't we simply us cin

You don't "need" to. You *could* hardcode the usage of `std::cin` if you wanted to. But, this way, the function works with *any* input stream. It's more useful that way. Now you can pass it a reference to a stringstream, a filestream… all without changes. The standard library is designed to be used in this way, hence the inheritance heirarchy.

> also why a reference of type istream is returned?

It's hard to be sure without any context, but this is commonly done to allow *chaining*.

Comment: Please Excuse me.I am a beginner. I didn't understand the stringstream,filestream thing. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @user8114776: No you can read about it in your C++ book. This is not the place to teach the language

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because in may not be mandatory std::cin - it can be any other istream